# The pronunciation of two consecutive O's

Tags: pronunciation, british-english

I came across such a sentence (‘Cakes and ale: or the skeleton in the cupboard’):

> She looked no older than when last I saw her six years before.

And I stumbled over this *‘no older’* reading it aloud (just as an articulation exercise). Should it sound /əʊəʊ/? I doubt it. Or is it just /nəʊɒldə/? By the way, I can't pronounce the former one without pausing on a little bit.

Comment: Thanks a lot, BoldBen! I'll memorise this difference in BrE and AmE meanings too.  And did I have to put a comma before 'too' in my sentence, according to BrE?

Comment: It seems to me possible to separate the two o's by a glottal stop or a w.

Comment: @GregLee: intrusive w! Sounds interesting. :)

Comment: @ArtyomLugovoy I'd agree with Greg Lee. I think a slight 'w' sound exists at the end of the word 'no' in many British accents, though I think absent from a lot of Scottish accents (we're probably doing the glottal stop because our 'o' sound can be quite different, though I'm afraid I haven't the terminology to explain the difference). So it might be less that a 'w' is inserted than that a trailing 'w' from the 'no' becomes more perceptible when followed by another similarly sounded 'o'.

Comment: The 'w' isn't really intrusive, just a slight moving of the lips towards that position, unlike in a single word such as "hour" and would only be present when talking quite fast.

Comment: Thanks, Spagirl and Weather Vane! That's really useful! And tell me, please: should I avoid that 'w' in the word 'owl', even when speaking fast, or not?

Comment: You can also separate the o's in "no older" with a glottal stop, if you don't like inserting the 'w'. What you shouldn't do is combine them to get an extra long 'o' sound.

Comment: *What you shouldn't do is combine them...* Yes, of course, I realise that, never would try to do both at the same time. And I wouldn't say I don't like inserting the 'w', I think I'd like to use both: the 'w' sound for fast speech and a glottal stop for a slow somewhat solemn speech, the latter being a rarer case.

Comment: A sound like [w] is normal in British speech in this situation. It's normal because speech is normally connected, and because the off-glide of the vowel in "no" is like the sound [w]. An example of how natural it is in British speech: we took the French word *noël* and anglicised it as "nowell" with a w.